# How best to return a Variant Array from a Java UDF

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, variant

I am writing a Java UDF function and I want to return an Array of Variants. It appears Snowflake supports returning an array of various Java primitive types and String, but not Variants. The documentation says an ARRAY is always an array of VARIANT so it seems unusual that this is not supported. The closest that I've come to is to specify the UDF function return type as an ARRAY but specify the Java function return type as a String and essentially return a json array string. E.g.

```java
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION()
    RETURNS ARRAY
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    PACKAGES = ('com.snowflake:snowpark:1.7.0')
    HANDLER = 'MyClass.myFunction'
    AS $$
        import java.util.stream.Stream;
        import com.snowflake.snowpark_java.types.Variant;
        public class MyClass {
            public static String myFunction(Variant input) {
                Variant[] result = EXTRACT_VALUES(input);
                return "[" \\
                  + Stream.of(result).map(Variant::asJsonString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) \\
                  + "]";
            }
        }
    $$;
```

The thing to understand is that I don't know the types of the array elements beforehand and they can be different types within the same array. The conversion between Variant::asJsonString and back and forth seems suboptimal especially since the code in EXTRACT_VALUES may also be converting elements back and forth

(from https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000D7qYtKAJ/how-best-to-return-a-variant-array-from-a-java-udf)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to return an array of variants. If you do so, you get the error:

`100315 (P0000): Unsupported return type: com.snowflake.snowpark_java.types.Variant[] in function JAVA_VARIANTS with handler MyClass.myFunction`

Instead, use the fact that a Variant can also be an array, so just return Variant:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION java_variants(x variant)
RETURNS variant
LANGUAGE JAVA
PACKAGES = ('com.snowflake:snowpark:1.7.0')
HANDLER = 'MyClass.myFunction'
AS $$
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    import com.snowflake.snowpark_java.types.Variant;
    public class MyClass {
        public static Variant myFunction(Variant input) {
            return input;
        }
    }
$$;

select java_variants([1, {'a':3}, '2020-09-12'::date]);

-- [   1,   {     "a": 3   },   "2020-09-12" ]
```

We can go deeper - for example we can convert the input Variant into an Array, and then convert that Array back into a Variant:

```java
        public static Variant myFunction(Variant input) {
            return new Variant(input.asArray());
        }
```